# Qt3D signal not sent or not caught

Tags: qt, qt6, qt-signals, qt3d

Based on the official example given in Qt, I try to catch keys inputs using Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler.

So after the following piece of code:

```
Qt3DCore::QTransform *sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
OrbitTransformController *controller = new OrbitTransformController(sphereTransform);
controller->setTarget(sphereTransform);
controller->setRadius(20.0f);
```

I add :

```
Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler *keyboardHandler = new Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler(rootEntity);
keyboardHandler->setSourceDevice(new Qt3DInput::QKeyboardDevice(rootEntity));

QObject::connect(keyboardHandler,
                 &Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler::pressed,
                 controller,
                 &::OrbitTransformController::onPressed);

rootEntity->addComponent(keyboardHandler);
```

But the signal is never caught or maybe ever sent.
What am I missing ? Attaching my object to another Qt3DCore::QEntity doesn't fix anything.

The official complete example without my adds :
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3d-simple-cpp-example.html

**EDIT 1:**

I add more important code snippets with my comments:

orbittransformcontroller.h :

```
class OrbitTransformController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Qt3DCore::QTransform* target READ target WRITE setTarget NOTIFY targetChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(float radius READ radius WRITE setRadius NOTIFY radiusChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(float angle READ angle WRITE setAngle NOTIFY angleChanged)
public:
    OrbitTransformController(QObject *parent = 0);
    ...
public slots:
    // Begin my Code
    void onPressed(Qt3DInput::QKeyEvent *event);
    // End my Code
    ...
};
```

orbittransformcontroller.cpp :

```
...
// Begin my Code
void OrbitTransformController::onPressed(Qt3DInput::QKeyEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "OrbitTransformController::onPressed !";
}
// End my Code
```

the main.cpp :

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene()
{
    // The original code :
    ...
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;
    OrbitTransformController *controller = new OrbitTransformController(sphereTransform);
    controller->setTarget(sphereTransform);
    controller->setRadius(20.0f);
    
    // Begin my Code
    Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler *keyboardHandler = new Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler(rootEntity);
    keyboardHandler->setSourceDevice(new Qt3DInput::QKeyboardDevice(rootEntity));

    QObject::connect(keyboardHandler, &Qt3DInput::QKeyboardHandler::pressed, controller, &::OrbitTransformController::onPressed);

    rootEntity->addComponent(keyboardHandler);
    // End my Code
    ...
}
```

Nothing more ! You will have noticed that Qt3D documentation and examples are quite light :(

Comment: What exactly is the `OrbitTransformController`? Your own one? Because there is the `QOrbitCameraController` which already supports moving by keyboard. Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That would make it easier to investigate.

Comment: If you're not sure that the signal is being sent, you can create another connection for that signal that does something reliable, like a qDebug() statement. This would at least help you isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I added the EDIT1.